# Azure compute emulator is not starting and getting stuck at starting roles for the application after windows update

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-sdk-.net

I am developing a WCF application and it is working fine in hosting environment. Now I am facing an issue after applying latest windows updates. Azure computer emulator is not starting, it is getting stuck at starting roles. So it is not possible to update the version of the application which is hosted as local debugging is not working because of the emulator issue.My windows version is Windows 8.1. Please see the screenshot of the emulator and see at which point it is stuck:

[image]

I tried the following things:

1. Edited "AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config" file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator" and changed the service urls

   Previously the ports were 10000, 10001 and 10002 respectively.
2. Tried to repair the Azure SDK. Currently I am using Azure SDK version 2.7.1 and currently it is not possible to update the version

The issue happened after applying the following windows security updates:

[image]

After doing all these things, it is not working. Please suggest any solution.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use default ports for storage emulator?

Comment: @Gaurav The same issue is happening while trying with default ports

Comment: Can you also please check event logs? You may find some information in there as to why your emulator is not starting.

Comment: I checked the eventlogs and could not find any useful information

Comment: Did you find the cause of the issue? I have a very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926079/role-in-azure-compute-emulator-stuck-cycling-between-unknown-and-destroyed-state Though I don't know when it started happening.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. I commented out the Startup Task in the csdef file, because those tasks were not necessary for debugging. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Check on the development properties if your emulator starts if you run your app. If the value is false change it to true.

That's how i solved it on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the following line in your web.config

```
<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is, this hang occurs when using the “Use IIS Web Server” option under “Local Development Server” settings in the Windows Azure project’s properties-->Web tab. 
The hang does not occur when you use the “Use IIS Express” setting which is the default.

This resolved my issue.

You can give it a try.